# How syntax the loop count within a string?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, tcsh

I want to `fgrep` a file (`query.file`) from several other files that share the same name, except one number (`i`) between two dots. e.g. `string.string.1.1KG.v2` and `string.string.2.1KG.v2`.

I used this code:

```
set i=1
while ($i<23)
fgrep -w -f query.file string.string.'$i'.1KG.v2 | awk '{print $1, $2}' >> output.$i
@ i++
end
```

But I get this error:

```
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have tried some other forms, but could not get this to work.

What should be the syntax for `i`?

Comment: Are you really using C-shell for scripting?

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, so remove the quotes around `$i`.

Comment: @Barmar. Yes, I use tcsh

Comment: @Barmar. That does not work either!

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Comment: @Barmar, How could I do the same thing in `bash`?

Comment: without the single quotes, the code is sound.

Comment: the problem is probably an empty query.file, if I were to guess

Comment: @MarkArmstrong. It does not work without quote either. The `query.file` is not empty.

Comment: @MarkArmstrong Why would an empty input file to `fgrep` cause the shell to complain of a syntax error?

Comment: @user2162153 Are you sure you're running the script with `tcsh`, i.e. does it begin with `#!/bin/tcsh`?

Comment: @Barmar, Yes, it starts with `#!bin/tcsh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible equivalent [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=1;i<23;i++)); do
    fgrep -w -f query.file string.string.$i.1KG.v2 | awk '{print $1, $2}' >> output.$i
done
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `i=1`, not `i=0`?